# How to add background image in header with 2 times bigger logo

Tags: css, wordpress

Here is a topbar of my website in wordpress

```
/* Masthead */

#masthead {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(109, 104, 110, 0.9);
  border-top: 10px solid #125CAA;
}
body.admin-bar #masthead {
  top: 0px;
}
header#masthead.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.site-logo {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
#masthead .right-nav {
  float: right;
}
#masthead .left-nav {
  float: left;
}
#masthead .right-nav > li,
#masthead .left-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#masthead .right-nav li a,
#masthead .left-nav > li a {
  color: #fff;
}
li.search {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.show-hide {
  display: none !important;
}
/* Masthead Sticky */

#masthead-placeholder {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
#masthead.sticky {
  /*top: 0;*/
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(109, 104, 110, 0.9);
}
```

1. I want to set background image. I used background: url('/wp-content/themes/day-spa/images/background.png'); 
   in main #masthead { but not worked
2. I want to keep masthead height same but need to place logo 2 times bigger then height of the #masthead

Please advise

Comment: A CSS preprocessor could do the math for that.

Comment: I become able to add image but its height is not the same like masthead height

Comment: Use CSS [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) `scale()`. Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_scale)

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working but what about my point 2. Can you please advise

Comment: @Ghayel my comment about a CSS preprocessor addressed your point #2. Bootstrap does similar with their topbar in calculating padding.

Comment: please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @coozin I am using wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for to formate your site logo. Check if this help you

```
.site-logo
{
    !content: '';    
    position: absolute;  
    width: 98px;
    height: 75px; 
    !top: -32px;
    left: 5%;
    !background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
```